# Understanding Pointers (in C): converting int pointer to char and changing values

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

I have the following code, which deals with pointers in C

```
void
f(void)
{
    int a[4];
    int *b = malloc(16);
    int *c;
    int i;

    printf("1: a = %p, b = %p, c = %p\n", a, b, c);

    c = a;
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
         a[i] = 100 + i;

    c[0] = 200;
    printf("2: a[0] = %d, a[1] = %d, a[2] = %d, a[3] = %d\n",
           a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3]);

    c[1] = 300;
    *(c + 2) = 301;
    3[c] = 302;
    printf("3: a[0] = %d, a[1] = %d, a[2] = %d, a[3] = %d\n",
           a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3]);

    c = c + 1;
    *c = 400;
    printf("4: a[0] = %d, a[1] = %d, a[2] = %d, a[3] = %d\n",
           a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3]);

    c = (int *) ((char *) c + 1);

    *c = 500;
    printf("5: a[0] = %d, a[1] = %d, a[2] = %d, a[3] = %d\n",
           a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3]);

    b = (int *) a + 1;
    c = (int *) ((char *) a + 1);
    printf("6: a = %p, b = %p, c = %p\n", a, b, c);
}

int
main(int ac, char **av)
{
    f();
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1: a = 0x7fff5fbff710, b = 0x1003002e0, c = 0x100000000
2: a[0] = 200, a[1] = 101, a[2] = 102, a[3] = 103
3: a[0] = 200, a[1] = 300, a[2] = 301, a[3] = 302
4: a[0] = 200, a[1] = 400, a[2] = 301, a[3] = 302
5: a[0] = 200, a[1] = 128144, a[2] = 256, a[3] = 302
6: a = 0x7fff5fbff710, b = 0x7fff5fbff714, c = 0x7fff5fbff711
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

I understand why a[1] is 128144 (we're moving a byte forward when we cast the int pointer to char +1 and over-write 500), but I don't understand why a[2] is 256 [the first bit will get over-written, but that doesn't give 256]. I'll highly appreciate help! Thanks in advance :)

Comment: While it may not be the cause of your issue here, I highly recommend you read about strict aliasing rules and unaligned memory accesses

Answer (score 2):

Short answer:  You modified `c` so it no longer has 4-byte integer alignment, and setting it to 500 modified two of the array elements.  Also, that unaligned access is generally a no-no and will cause alignment faults on some systems.

Long answer:  At step 4, `a[1]` contains 0x00000190 which is 400, and `a[2]` contains 0x0000012D which is 301.

Let's assume `a[0]` starts at memory address 0.  Here is how the bytes are arranged in a **little-endian** system (the endianness is very important here), left-to-right from 0 to 15:

```
ADDR: 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F  
DATA: C8 00 00 00 90 01 00 00 2D 01 00 00 2E 01 00 00
```

At step 5 you've unaligned `c` by one byte via your cast to a `char *`, so it points to address `05` instead of `04`.  You assign the value 500 (0x000001F4) to it, which overwrites the bytes from 05-08, resulting in this memory:

```
ADDR: 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F  
DATA: C8 00 00 00 90 F4 01 00 00 01 00 00 2E 01 00 00
```

When you read `a[1]` you get 0x0001F490 which is 128144.
When you read `a[2]` you get 0x00000100 which is 256.

Answer (score 0):

the thing to realize is that this

```
c = (int *) ((char *) c + 1);
```

makes c point to some of a[1] and some of a[2]. You move c over by one byte and that make that a int pointer. This makes *c address the last 3 bytes of a[1] and the first byte of a[2]. Draw out all the bits and see what happens

Comment: I did exactly that it gives a[1] = 128144 (which matches).
However, a[2] does not come out to be 256, could you try it on your end? (I can post an image of what it looks like on my end - if it helps; let me know)

Comment: This is presumably undefined behavior.

Comment: Andrew has done the heavy lifting for us and shown you how this happens, I left it as an excercise for you